# Formula for subtracting number range in one cell from a number in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have:

- a column with a number range represented as a string separated by a dash: "X-Y"
- a column with a single number

What I'd like is a formula to subtract each the left and right numbers (X, Y) from the solo number to produce another range.

Example:

```
Range cell        "5-9"  
Solo number cell  "2000"
Result wanted     "1995-1991"
```

How can I produce this?

I am currently using a formula that requires me to manually enter the numbers on either side of the dash.  Example (notice 5 and 9 are hard-coded):

```
=SUM(A31,-5)&"-"&SUM(A31,-9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say A1=2000
And B1="5-9"

You can use a combination of FIND, LEFT/RIGHT, and INT functions:

```
C1 =(A1-INT(LEFT(B1,FIND("-",B1)-1))&"-"&(A1-INT(RIGHT(B1,FIND("-",B1)-1))))
```

This will work with any range like "100-135"

Comment: Why use `Int()`? Does it force the formula to treat the `Left()` and `Right()` parts as Integers?  ...wouldn't it anyways, since the range is going to be digits? Or might Excel treat it as text, and you want to make sure it uses the numbers as an integer?

Comment: I said B1="5-9", which is a string literal.  Unless there is some other way to specify range that I don't know, left() would return a substring which you need to convert to a number.

Comment: @BruceWayne, Actually you're right, I removed the INT as a test and it still works.  This is because =100-"2" turns into 98 to my surprise.  However, I will leave INT() in my answer as I don't know if I trust this behaviour.  Might be version specific?

Comment: That worked spectacularly! Excel added another parenthesis at the end, but otherwise, your formula was spot on. Cheers.

Comment: @ergonaut - I agree in keeping `Int()`, better safe than sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your range numbers will be 0-9, you can use this:

```
=SUM(A31,-LEFT(B31,1))&"-"&SUM(A31,-RIGHT(B31,1))
```

(assuming the range number is in column B)

edit: @ergonaut has a better solution that will use any amount of digits.

Answer (score 0):

If A1 is 2000 and B1 is 5-9:

```
=A1-MID(B1,1,FIND("-",B1)-1)&"-"&A1-MID(B1,FIND("-",B1)+1,99)
```

Comment: Thank you! This also gave me the outcome I was hoping for.